# change date format in a nested xml field without xml parsing

Tags: xml, date, awk, sed, format

I have a XML file who's lines are like

```
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>ACME Pinerolo TO - 31/05/2017</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>SOME OTHER COMPANY Caselecchio BO - 21/06/2016</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
...

     <Placemark>
```

and the final result who I want to achieve is

```
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>TO 170531 ACME Pinerolo TO</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>BO 160821 SOME OTHER COMPANY Caselecchio</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
```

I think it is possible to use awk, sed, xargs, without parsing the XML but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed for EREs and \s+\S:

```
$ sed -E 's:(<name>)(.*)\s+(\S+\s+)-\s+([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/[0-9]{2}([0-9]+):\1\3\6\5\4 \2:' file
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>TO 170531 ACME Pinerolo</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
...
     <Placemark>
       <name>BO 160621 SOME OTHER COMPANY Caselecchio</name>
   ...
     </Placemark>
...

     <Placemark>
```

idk how to make "TO" appear at the end of 1 line but not "BO" at the end of the other or how to transform `21/**06**/2016` into `16**08**21` - I think those are typos in your expected output.

The above is, of course, fragile and based on the limited information and example in your question so YMMV using it on other data.

Comment: Yes, you guessed right: it was a typo error. It works, thanks